# CSS circle border fill animation

Tags: css, animation, border, geometry

I have a css file which makes circle border fill animation perfectly. Its in 100px width and height. But i need only in 50px width and height circle with the same animation. I tried many more times to minimize the size, but the circle not get correctly fix with animation. please help me to smaller this circle.
My need:
Width-50px
Height -50px
border size as per the image file attached -[circle border fill sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRqjm.jpg)

> ## My code

```
#loading
{   
  width: 100px;  
  height: 100px;  
  margin: 30px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.outer-shadow, .inner-shadow
{
  z-index: 4;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.inner-shadow 
{
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: -40px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.hold 
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip: rect(0px, 100px, 100px, 50px);
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.fill, .dot span 
{
  background-color: #f50;
}

.fill 
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  clip: rect(0px, 50px, 100px, 0px);
}

.left .fill 
{
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-animation: left 1s linear ;
  -moz-animation: left 1s linear ;
  animation: left 1s linear both;  
}

@keyframes left 
{
  0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
  100%{transform:rotate(180deg);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes left 
{
  0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
  100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);}
}

.right 
{
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.right .fill 
{  
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-animation: right 1s linear ;
  -moz-animation: right 1s linear ;
  animation: right 1s linear both ;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes right 
{
  0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
  100%{transform:rotate(180deg);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes right 
{
  0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% {transform: rotate(180deg);}
}
```

My code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/rsfkmegp/)...!

Comment: I'd suggest you to use `transform: scale(0.5)` on the parent element like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/rsfkmegp/3/). That would halve the size of the circle without having to make any other change.

Comment: @Harry..... Thanks for your help Mr. Harry...  transform: scale(0.5) works .. superb..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to divide by 2 every values involved, even the clip(); ones  [(fiddle updated)](https://jsfiddle.net/rsfkmegp/2/)

```css
#loading {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.outer-shadow,
.inner-shadow {
  z-index: 4;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.inner-shadow {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.hold {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip: rect(0px, 50px, 50px, 25px);
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.fill,
.dot span {
  background-color: #f50;
}
.fill {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  clip: rect(0px, 25px, 50px, 0px);
}
.left .fill {
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-animation: left 1s linear;
  -moz-animation: left 1s linear;
  animation: left 1s linear both;
}
@keyframes left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
.right {
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.right .fill {
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-animation: right 1s linear;
  -moz-animation: right 1s linear;
  animation: right 1s linear both;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
@keyframes right {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes right {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
.inner-shadow img {
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div id='loading'>
  <div class='outer-shadow'>
  </div>
  <div class='inner-shadow'>
  </div>
  <div class='hold left'>
    <div class='fill'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='hold right'>
    <div class='fill'></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**edit:** in respond to comment @Filipe

> How would the change from clip to clip-path be? I tried (also changing rect to inset), but the animation stops working.

Possible example with clip-path instead clip .

```css
#loading {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.outer-shadow,
.inner-shadow {
  z-index: 4;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.inner-shadow {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.hold {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 50% 100%);
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.fill,
.dot span {
  background-color: #f50;
}

.fill {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 50% 100%);
}

.left .fill {
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-animation: left 1s linear;
  -moz-animation: left 1s linear;
  animation: left 1s linear both;
}

@keyframes left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

.right {
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.right .fill {
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-animation: right 1s linear;
  -moz-animation: right 1s linear;
  animation: right 1s linear both;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes right {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes right {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

.inner-shadow img {
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div id='loading'>
  <div class='outer-shadow'>
  </div>
  <div class='inner-shadow'>
  </div>
  <div class='hold left'>
    <div class='fill'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='hold right'>
    <div class='fill'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice work.. Its working with small circle as i need.. Thanks Mr. GCyrillus....

Comment: Hi this is work well except safari browser,  can you give me a solution for safari?

Comment: **Update 2019:** CSS `clip` property is deprecated. You should use `clip-path` instead - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip#See_also .

Comment: How would the change from `clip` to `clip-path` be? I tried (also changing `rect` to `inset`), but the animation stops working.

Comment: @Filipe I added a snippet in my answer using clip-path instead clip .  To help you draw clip-path, here is an online tool https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Answer (score 0):

is this what you expect,hope this will help to you.try this.I only concerned about the circle size of 50 px with inside circle.if this is not the case tell me.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>jquery</title>

<style type="text/css">
  div.circleone{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px black;

  }

  div.circletwo
  {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 12.5px;
    box-shadow: 1px -1px 1px black;
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;


  }

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="circleone">
  <div class="circletwo"></div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```