# changing border-color slowly from left to right

Tags: css, border, css-transitions

I can change a border colour on hover easily enough, see here:
https://jsfiddle.net/vdcLzw2a/10/

```
.box{
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition : border 500ms ease-out;
}

.box:hover{
  border-color: red;
  transition: border 0.25 ease-out;
}
```

is there an easy way to make the transition slowly so that once you hover, it goes from left to right and is almost drawing a line over the top of the original border rather than highlighting it all at the same time?

Comment: you mean a circular movement ?

Comment: You should refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35383629/css-circle-border-fill-animation)

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes circular, sorry should have specified that