# Javascript - Timer disabling after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, timer

I have got code for timer and its working fine. But I need to customize that by disabling it using fade out  effect after 5 seconds.

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

Comment: so... where exactly are you stuck? It's unclear

Comment: Hey Jeremy Thille, sorry I'm new in javascript things. I was swarching for script for timer and I got one. Excatly what i need is only seconds. And there is a video playing in background. The video should play after three seconds. So I need 3 seconds timer and it should disable when it reach three seconds.

Comment: If you just need the video to start after three seconds, you can use the good old setTimeout function: setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);

Comment: I'm using that also. But I need to show the 3 second timer with that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we are setting to `counter` to **5** and timer to tick every **1000ms** or **1s** and in every tick we check if  we have reached below **0** if we have then we will setop the timer, remove timer diplay and show content by calling display function

Update: you asked for a loading like animation. I added it to the answer but the code is not mine. I took it from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35383629/css-circle-border-fill-animation). You can ask him any questions you have regarding the code of the animation.

```js
var display = function(){
    document.getElementById("content").style.display = "inline";
}

var myTimer = function(){
var counter = 5;
var timer = setInterval(function(){
        if(counter <= 0){
            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
            display();
        }else{
            if(counter == 5){
                document.getElementById("loading").className = "loading";
                document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "block";
            }
            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = counter--;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

myTimer();
```

```css
.loading {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    position: relative;
}
.inner-shadow {
    z-index: 4;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.inner-shadow {
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.hold {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    clip: rect(0px, 50px, 50px, 25px);
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.fill,
.dot span {
    background-color: #f50;
}
.fill {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    clip: rect(0px, 25px, 50px, 0px);
}
.left .fill {
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-animation: left 2.5s linear;
    -moz-animation: left 2.5s linear;
    animation: left 2.5s linear both;
}
@keyframes left {
0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}
100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes left {
0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}
100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
}
.right {
    z-index: 3;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.right .fill {
    z-index: 3;
    -webkit-animation: right 2.5s linear;
    -moz-animation: right 2.5s linear;
    animation: right 2.5s linear both;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 2.5s;
    animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
@keyframes right {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes right {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id='loading' class="loading" style="display:none;">
    <div class='inner-shadow' id="timer">
    </div>
    <div class='hold left'>
        <div class='fill'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='hold right'>
        <div class='fill'></div>
    </div>
</div>
<p id="content" style="display:none;" >Hello</p>
```

Comment: Thanks bro :) I'm trying using this.

Comment: Hey Andam, its working fine. And one ? can we add moving border animation to this? Like timer circle?

Comment: @am_dev like analog clock

Comment: Not excatly, I need to start a border when it is second 1 and have to finish when it get second 5. Like this  https://codepen.io/dydric/pen/OMJPLP

Comment: http://dev.netbramha.in/projects/timer/practice%20shots.html This is my link I'm working on please check.

Comment: The border should start from on point and connect to that point after rotating based on the seconds

Comment: @am_dev is it fine to be in css

Comment: If you  go through each pages by clicking on screen you will reach a screen of practice section. Like practice section1,2,3 and final. That combining of each screens I'm trying to do. Please share your knowledge on that.

Comment: @am_dev currenty I dont have extra time on. I will try to go through it when I finish my tasks.

Comment: @am_dev I updated the answer. I think thats what you asked for.